# remove whitespace between php variable and html characters

Tags: php, html, variables, whitespace

I have in php: `$currencysymbol = "£"`

And later I want to use it in html to show: `£1 = xxxxx`

But how do I get rid of the whitespace between the symbol and the 1?

```
$currencysymbol 1 = xxxxx //whitespace £ 1
$currencysymbol1 = xxxxx // unknown variable
```

Comment: in html use as <?php echo $currencysymbol."1"; ?>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
<?php
     echo $currencysymbol."1" = xxxxx;
?>
```